# Can't find the webcam Dell Latitude E6540

Tags: webcam, dell-latitude

When I search for webcam, camera, cam nothing turns up. I can turn on the camera from online services, but I do not know how to do it offline.

Comment: What online services? And what are you actually trying to do with the camera?

Comment: I mainly want to use the camera for taking pictures and videoes. When I couldn´t find the camera on the computer I used webcamtoy.com and allowed them to find the camera and they could. The computers programs are installed with capainstaller (it´s a work computer), can this be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that it's a work computer, they probably removed the management software for the webcam.

You also said that the camera worked when you went to a website. That's because the website uses a plugin called Flash, and since you gave it permission to access your webcam, you were able to get your webcam to work.

Chances are that you're not going to be able to install any software on your computer. Your best option would be going on websites similar to what you've found.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a recording software like
[this](http://www.nchsoftware.com/capture/).
If it works with Adobe Flash PLayer in Browser the driver it's installed, so you need only a software for recording the video.I don't realy understand what you need...You can use it on skype?